# Using useless object.self.self.. or Class.self.self.. is ever need?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Let's write a simple class to explain in my head :

```
class SomeClass {
    var happyToUsed = 10
}
```

And create an object

```
let someObject = SomeClass()
```

and use its property for case 1:

```
someObject.happyToUsed  // prints 10
```

for case 2:

```
someObject.self.happyToUsed // prints 10
```

and case 3

```
someObject.self.self.self.self.happyToUsed  // prints 10 compiler is still ok, even if self count 1k
```

I know case 1 and case 2 is same ( directly point the same object ). Even if I have used SomeClass.self rather than objects cases will act the same way. I ever used case 3 in a project so far.

My question is there any example case 3 which I should prefer or negative effect on memory management?

Comment: I don't see the point of this question really but since the recommendation is to not use `self` unless really needed so for your code only case 1 is the correct use of `self`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks, I ever used before case 3, but I just wonder case 3 has a point or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [Postfix Self Expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID401) according to the Swift reference:

> A postfix self expression consists of an expression or the name of a type, immediately followed by `.self`
>
> The first form evaluates to the value of the expression. For example, x.self evaluates to x.

The fact that you can write `.self` indefinitely is just a side effect of this definition. Since `x.self` is an expression itself, you can add `.self` to it too. And you can do this forever.

That doesn't mean you *should* though.

These do the same thing:

```
let x                         =                          10
let x = 10
```

Hopefully you'd agree that the second one reads better. Similarly, `.self` is generally redundant. According to [this discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/grammar-of-postfix-self-expression/39316), it seems like `.self` is really just a legacy from Objective-C. IMO it also makes syntaxes like the identity key path (`\.self`) "make more sense".

Answer (score 1):

There are no differences between them, ultimately you are pointing to the same instance; Classes are reference types so whatever happens, it will always point to the same reference; You don't need to repeat it as it takes the same location in the memory which is already reserved.

Comment: Thank you but I didn`t ask what the reference type is.

Comment: I know, I just added it as an extra explanation