# Using type as a value, why is the "self" keyword required here?

Tags: swift, function, types, arguments

I'm currently learning type as a value in functions and wrote this sample code to play around:

```
import Foundation

class Animal {
    func sound() {
        print("Generic animal noises")
    }
}

func foo(_ t:Animal) {
    print("Hi")
}

foo(Animal) //Cannot convert value of type 'Animal.Type' to expected argument type 'Animal'
```

**I'm not surprised by this result.** Obviously you cant pass the type itself as an argument where an instance of that type is expected. But notice that the compiler says that the argument I passed was of type `Animal.Type`. So if I did this, it should compile right?

```
func foo(_ t:Animal.Type) {
    print("Hi")
}

foo(Animal) //Expected member name or constructor call after type name
```

This is what really confuses me a heck ton, *the compiler told me it was of type* `Animal.Type` *but after making this change  it once again shows an error.

Of course I listened to the fix  Swift suggests and do:

```
foo(Animal.self) //Works correctly
```

---

But my biggest question is: **WHY?** Isn't `Animal` itself the type? Why does the compiler require me to use `Animal.self` to get the type? This really confuses me, I would like for some guidance.

Comment: By defining ```Animal.Type``` you just pass parameter type you can not use t parameter member inside the function without creating an object. You can check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41709040/14733292

Comment: I _think_ this is just an aesthetic choice of language design, rather than because of some technical difficulties. It is to make it absolutely clear what is a _type_, and what is a _value_ representing a type.

Comment: @RajaKishan That link certainly does help a bit in understanding, but I'm still confused as to why `.self` was even needed. Thanks for your help, nonetheless.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal I have asked a similar one to your question. Please check it out
https://stackoverflow.com/q/65369113/14531220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-answering, with help of comments, I was able to find out the reason:

---

Using `.self` after the type name is called [Postfix Self Expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID401):

> A postfix self expression consists of an expression or the name of a
> type, immediately followed by `.self`. It has the following forms:
>
> ```
> expression.self
> ```
>
> ```
> type.self
> ```
>
> The first form evaluates to the value of the expression. For example, `x.self` evaluates to `x`.
>
> **The second form evaluates to the value of the type. Use this form to access a type as a value.** For example, because SomeClass.self evaluates to the SomeClass type itself, you can pass it to a function or method that accepts a type-level argument.

Thus, the `.self` keyword is required to consider the type as a value capable of being passed as an argument to functions.