# How to add variable to a struct which does not part of decodable?

Tags: swift, codable

I would use `nodesWithDepth` out of decodable:

this worked before:

```swift
public struct NEWTREE: Equatable, Codable {
    public var Filename: String
    public var GROUP: [GROUP]
    public var ITEM: [ITEM]
    public var CATEGORY: [CATEGORY]
    public var ROOT: ROOT
```

but the modified not:

```swift
public struct NEWTREE: Equatable, Codable {
    public var Filename: String
    public var GROUP: [GROUP]
    public var ITEM: [ITEM]
    public var CATEGORY: [CATEGORY]
    public var ROOT: ROOT
    public var nodesWithDepth: [(text: String, depth: Int, type: TreeData2)]?
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        Filename = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .Filename)
        GROUP = try container.decode([GROUP].self, forKey: .GROUP)
        ITEM = try container.decode([ITEM].self, forKey: .ITEM)
        CATEGORY = try container.decode([CATEGORY].self, forKey: .CATEGORY)
        ROOT = try container.decode(ROOT.self, forKey: .ROOT)
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case Filename
        case GROUP
        case ITEM
        case CATEGORY
        case ROOT
    }
```

but this raise an error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[[GROUP]]' to expected argument type '[GROUP].Type'

How can I fix?

Comment: Please stop to name variables/properties **and** types uppercase. `var GROUP: [GROUP]` is confusing.

Comment: XML is formatted like so, but you can propose how to change the code.

Comment: Look at Sweeper's answer, the struct names are arbitrary and for the properties add CodingKeys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift is confused by expressions such as

```
[GROUP].self
```

Apparently, the compiler thinks that `GROUP` here refers to the property `GROUP`, rather than the type `GROUP`. [Note that it is totally valid to add `.self` to any expression,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65369113/using-useless-object-self-self-or-class-self-self-is-ever-need/65369316#65369316) without changing what it means.

So effectively, you are passing a one-element array, containing the value of the property `GROUP`. This expression has the type `[[GROUP]]`, but `decode` obviously expects a decodable metatype, hence the error.

Or in the case of `ROOT`, you are passing the value of the `ROOT` property, which has the type `ROOT`, but `decode` obviously expects a decodable metatype.

This behaviour can be shown with a more minimal example like this:

```
struct A {}
struct B {
    let A: A

    func f() {
        print(A.self)
        print([A].self)
    }
}

B(A: A()).f()
print("-------")
print(A.self)
print([A].self)
```

The two print statements outside `B` prints metatypes, whereas the ones inside `B` prints an instance of `A` and an array.

---

You can solve this ambiguity by using the long form of the array type, `Array<Group>.self`

```
GROUP = try container.decode(Array<GROUP>.self, forKey: .GROUP)
```

Or introduce a type alias in cases such as `ROOT`:

```
typealias ROOTType = ROOT

...

ROOT = try container.decode(ROOTType.self, forKey: .ROOT)
```

But of course, none of this would have happened if you adhered to the Swift naming guidelines, and did:

```
var groups: [Group]
```

If you want the coding keys to all be capitalised, you can do it in the coding keys enum:

```
public struct NewTree: Equatable, Codable {
    public var filename: String
    public var groups: [Group]
    public var items: [Item]
    public var categories: [Category]
    public var root: Root

    // consider making the tuple here into another struct...
    public var nodesWithDepth: [(text: String, depth: Int, type: TreeData2)]?

    // you don't actually need to write the custom decoding logic just because you added nodesWithDepth
    // Swift can figure it out from the CodingKeys enum because the
    // case names match the property names

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case filename = "Filename"
        case groups = "GROUP"
        case items = "ITEM"
        case categories = "CATEGORY"
        case root = "ROOT"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `GROUP = try container.decode(Array<GROUP>.self, forKey: .group)` worked, but what about this line? `ROOT = try container.decode(ROOT.self, forKey: .root)`

Comment: If there is no custom decoding logic, than I got this error: `Type 'NEWTREE' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`.

Comment: only for ROOT please, as ROOT is not an array

Comment: ahh yes, the **names of the enum cases** caused the issue

Comment: @János Okay, I think I've edited the all the points mentioned in the comments into the answer. I've also added a more minimal example of this rather confusing behaviour, that you can just paste into a playground and run.